# Which texts are assigned which to which cluster in K-means clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have used K-means on my TF-IDF matrix from my text documents. But now I want to know which texts have been assigned to which cluster. I have four clusters, so for example I want to know which texts are assigned to cluster 1, how do I do this? This is the code I used.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
min_df = 5,
max_df = 0.95,
max_features = 8000
)

tfidf.fit(df_m_a['text_final'])
text = tfidf.transform(df_m_a['text_final'])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4).fit(text)
```

Comment: `kmeans.labels_`, it corresponds to the original data set one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is scikit-learn, KMeans has an attribute `_cluster_centers` The  text will be in the cluster corresponding to the closest cluster center. Or `labels_` should also do it.

Comment: yes I get that, but is there a way to efficiently determine the cluster of every text in the dataset?